# Magento 2 - Split an order in two parts

Tags: magento2

I am trying to make a functionality to split an order in 2 which has 2 different **Seller Item** in my custom module.

Do you have any idea about how to do this pro-grammatically please ?

Answer (score 1):

Reference link [split orders in magento](https://niharika09.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/to-split-orders-in-magento-based-on-backorders/)

Reference link [Magento - 2](http://webkul.com/blog/marketplace-split-order-magento2/)

Comment: I am want to split my order pro-grammatically without using extension in magento 2. Is it possible? @Jitendra

Comment: I want to split order based on quantity any help?

Answer (score 1):

Is possible split the order by seller attribute. You just need to intercept the `placeOrder` function using `around` action plugin.
There, you can map all of the items into cart and create a new order for each product you want.
Please refer (In this case, split by product SKU `getSku`, you can change for any attribute):

```
public function aroundPlaceOrder(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    $cartId,
    $paymentMethod = null
) {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    $quotes = [];
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $quotes[$item->getProduct()->getSku()][] = $item;
    }

    foreach ($quotes as $groups => $items) {
    ...
```

Also, you can take a look here:
https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order/blob/develop/Plugin/SplitQuote.php

Thanks!

Comment: does collect totals work correctly? I am afraid cart price rules will not work if we are going to split order.

Comment: Works normally!

Comment: I want to split order based on quantity any help?